# Why does PyYAML 5.1 raise YAMLLoadWarning when the default loader has been made safer already?

Tags: angular, python-3.x, security, yaml, warnings

Here is my code:

```
import yaml
yaml.load('foo')
```

This code leads to the following warning with PyYAML (5.1).

```
$ pip install pyyaml
$ python3 foo.py
foo.py:2: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  yaml.load('foo')
```

So I visited https://msg.pyyaml.org/load to see what this is about but I do not understand the need for this warning.

First, the documentation says,

> `UnsafeLoader` (also called `Loader` for backwards compatability)
>
> The original Loader code that could be easily exploitable by untrusted data input.

Okay, that makes sense. In an earlier version, the original loader was unsafe. Further, it says,

> `FullLoader`
>
> Loads the full YAML language. Avoids arbitrary code execution. This is currently (PyYAML 5.1) the default loader called by `yaml.load(input)` (after issuing the warning).

So the current version uses `FullLoader` which is not unsafe. This is confirmed again in the document.

> The load function was also made **much** safer by disallowing the execution of arbitrary functions by the default loader (`FullLoader`).

If the current version that uses `FullLoader` is not unsafe, then why do we need the `YAMLLoadWarning` at all?

Comment: I think you should read "**much** safer"  as: *not as unsafe as the original, but still not completely safe*. You are reading it as that it is *safe* (i..e "not unsafe")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this warning is more like a notification & guidance to let the user know what is the PyYAML best practice in the future. Recall that: *Explicit is better than implicit.*

---

Before version 5.1 (e.g. [4.1](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/4.2b2/lib3/yaml/__init__.py#L65)), the `yaml.load` api use `Loader=Loader` as default:

```
def load(stream, Loader=Loader):
    """
    Parse the first YAML document in a stream
    and produce the corresponding Python object.
    """
    loader = Loader(stream)
    try:
        return loader.get_single_data()
    finally:
        loader.dispose()

def safe_load(stream):
    """
    Parse the first YAML document in a stream
    and produce the corresponding Python object.
    Resolve only basic YAML tags.
    """
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
```

At that time, there were only three available choice for [`Loader` class](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/4.2b2/lib3/yaml/loader.py): limited `BaseLoader`, `SafeLoader` and the unsafe `Loader`. Although the default one is unsafe, just like we read from the doc:

> PyYAML's `load` function has been unsafe since the first release in May
>   2006. It has always been documented that way in bold type: PyYAMLDocumentation. 
>   PyYAML has always provided a `safe_load` function that can load a subset of 
>   YAML without exploit.

But there are still a lot of resources and tutorials prefer using `yaml.load(f)` directly, so the users (and especially the new user) are choosing a default Loader class **implicitly**.

---

And since PyYAML version [5.1](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/5.1/lib3/yaml/__init__.py#L103), the `yaml.load` api is changed to be more **explicit**:

```
def load(stream, Loader=None):
    """
    Parse the first YAML document in a stream
    and produce the corresponding Python object.
    """
    if Loader is None:
        load_warning('load')
        Loader = FullLoader

    loader = Loader(stream)
    try:
        return loader.get_single_data()
    finally:
        loader.dispose()

def safe_load(stream):
    """
    Parse the first YAML document in a stream
    and produce the corresponding Python object.
    Resolve only basic YAML tags. This is known
    to be safe for untrusted input.
    """
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
```

And a new `FullLoader` is added into [`Loader` classes](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/5.1/lib3/yaml/loader.py). As users, we should also be aware of the changes and use `yaml.load` more **explicitly**:

- `yaml.load(stream, yaml.SafeLoader)`

  Recommended for untrusted input. Limitation: Loads a subset of the YAML language.
- `yaml.load(stream, yaml.FullLoader)`

  For more trusted input. Still a bit of Limitation: Avoids arbitrary code execution.
- `yaml.load(stream, yaml.Loader)` (`UnsafeLoader` is the same as `Loader`)

  Unsafe. But has the full power.